# Ruby code stuck in output loop

Tags: ruby, loops, output, erb

Updated code:

I need a list out put with this code

```
<div class="card mt-4">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <%= TodoItem.where(todo_list_id: @todo_list.id).each do |todoitem|%> 
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href = "/todo_items/<%=@todo_list.id %>"> 
          <%= TodoItem.find(@todo_list.id).description %>
        </a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<dl>
```

My output seems to be stuck on one item in the loop then everyhting comes after. How do I get the output(below) in the loop to show in the table
"

```
Call 1871 tomorrow
Call 1871 tomorrow
[#<TodoItem id: 2, todo_list_id: 2, created_at: "2018-06-15 00:27:52", updated_at: "2018-06-15 03:50:26", description: "Call 1871 tomorrow">, #<TodoItem id: 3, todo_list_id: 2, created_at: "2018-06-15 04:00:26", updated_at: "2018-06-15 04:00:26", description: "When to move ">]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you are?

Comment: Your output has __nothing__ to do with the code you show.

Comment: This loop will repeat for each movie by that director. Are you sure that's repeating the same movie?

Comment: What people are saying is that the output you show cannot be coming from the code you show. It's more likely the output is coming from a console, where `each` does, in fact, return the enumerator/collection you've called it on. Without seeing the actual code you're running, helping is problematic.

Comment: Its been updated

Comment: Hint: you're not doing anything with your `todoitem`. And your code doesn't crash only accidentally, because you happen to have a todo list and a todo item with the same ids.

Comment: Your `each` statement is within `<%= ... %>`, which means the result will be rendered. That's why you see the return result of `each`, which is the collection you've called `each` on, as I stated previously.

Comment: Unrelated, but this is classic n+1: you should be using a join/include (I forget which one), and you're doing work in the view that should be done in the controller.

Comment: @DaveNewton: `includes` eager loads related collection. `joins` doesn't load, but allows to use it for filtering (`where`). Learned the distinction myself only a few days ago :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks :) Haven't been doing much Rails lately :(

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is "stuck", your loop is working correctly but you're outputting the result of the `.each` call, which is the collection passed into `.each`, because you've wrapped it in `<%=` instead of `<%`.

You need to use `<% %>` around the Ruby code for the loop, and only use `<%=` on lines where you want to output the result to the browser.

Your loop should start with

```
<% TodoItem.where(... %>
```

not

```
<%= TodoItem.where(... %>
```

---

The second problem, and the reason you're seeing the same TodoItem's description printed multiple times, is you ignore the variable you're `.each` loop is providing, and instead query the database for the same TodoItem each loop.

Your loop's content should look like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <%= link_to todoitem.description, todoitem %>
</li>
```

Each iteration *already has* a `todoitem` made available to it, you don't need to query the database for a new `TodoItem` each loop.

Additionally, the query you were using was incorrect, and only happened to at all work by pure coincidence. You were querying a `TodoItem` by whatever `@todo_list.id`.

The line you previously had...

```
<%= TodoItem.find(@todo_list.id).description %>
```

uses `@todo_list.id` as the id of a `TodoItem`. That finds an unrelated `TodoItem` that *happens* to share a numeric ID with a `TodoList`. You're querying the same (wrong) `TodoItem` record each time, because `@todo_list.id` isn't changing inside your loop.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I want to output all items stored in ToDoItems descriptions not sure why it only outputs one of them multiple times

Comment: @DavidMomoh: look closely at that line. Why do you think it should print different results? What varies each iteration?

Comment: @DavidMomoh I didn't look closely enough at your code. You have two different issues here, one is the incorrect use of `<%=` and the other is that you're not actually using the `todoitem` variable inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks guys, a little more context here: TodoItem is a line item inside a Todolist. On the TodoList show page I want to see all the TodoItems associated with the specific TodoList. Hence the code I need to loop through every TodoItem that shares the same TodoListID

Comment: @DavidMomoh: "I want to see all the TodoItems associated with the specific TodoList." - yeah, that was kinda obvious. Meagar's explanations didn't make your mistakes crystal clear, I take it?

Comment: @DavidMomoh That's exactly what my code does. You're already finding all the TodoItems associated with the TodoList with your `where(todo_list_id: @todo_list.id)`. That part is done. Inside the loop, each `todoitem` is part of the set you've already queried, and that set *is* the set of items within the given TodoList. The line you've added inside the loop, `TodoItem.find(@todo_list.id)`, is nonsense. You can't `find` an item from table A with the Id of a record in table B, that isn't doing anything except finding the wrong record, and it will break when you have gaps in your sequential IDs.

Comment: Ah I understand now, I am new to Ruby but I am not sure I can directly call the TodoItem model in the TodoList page without sending a vaue from the route.rb file.

Comment: @DavidMomoh But again, please don't do it like this. With proper relations you do not need to do the n+1 queries.